# Panel pane visibility based on user entity reference

Tags: panels

I have a content type called 'company' with an entity reference field called 'company_managers' referencing users who will be allowed to add and edit other content types relating to this company.

The company node is displayed using panels. What I am struggling with is to create a visibility rule which will only show a panel-pane if the logged in user is referenced in the entity field 'company_managers' this will allow me to show panel panes specific to users in the 'company_managers' field.

So the psudo logic for the visibility rule would be: Check if logged in user is contained in 'company_managers' If yes show panel-pane if no dont show pane.

This seems such a simple use case that i dont want to create custom code it must be achievable 'out the box' I just cant seem to get to the answer. So after two days of researching am asking for help.

NOTE: have spoofed this behavior using the visibility rule content manager and manually selecting a user on this site. All I would need is to put in the logged in user but I dont think you can put in dynamic variables or tokens.

Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok figured this out. On the relevant panel pane used:

> Add New Rule:
>
> Select PHP Code:

Then put in the following:

```
foreach( $contexts['argument_entity_id:node_1']->data->field_managers['und'] as $key => $value) { $array []=  $value['target_id']; }
return in_array($contexts['logged-in-user']->data->uid ,$array);
```

Commentary:
This piece of code loops through my entity reference field called field_managers on this node which references users and creates an array of user IDS.

```
foreach( $contexts['argument_entity_id:node_1']->data->field_managers['und'] as $key => $value) { $array []=  $value['target_id']; }
```

This line returns true if the logged-in-user ID is part of the array created by the code above. Uses the `in_array` php function.

```
return in_array($contexts['logged-in-user']->data->uid ,$array);
```

The following discussion was useful to finding the solution listed above.
https://drupal.org/node/1198282

NOTE: in the above example if you replace field_managers with the name of your user entity reference field that should be the only alteration you will need to make this work for you.

Comment: Saving PHP code in the database is generally discouraged since this is a security issue. The best way to solve this is to create a CTools access plugin. See here for an example: http://ramlev.dk/blog/2012/03/30/create-a-ctools-access-plugin/